# Floated element doesn't stick to top of parent wrapper div

Tags: css, html, css-float

I have 3 divs in wrapper. I want 2 of them to stick to top-left and they need to be under each other. Third div needs to stick to top-right, but doesn't stick to top.

**This is how I tried to do it but failed:** http://jsfiddle.net/TZ82X/

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="logo">Logo</div>
  <div id="motto">Motto</div>
  <div id="nav">Navigation</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
  background: #CCC;
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: auto;
}
#logo {
  background: tomato;
  width: 300px;
  height: 20px;
  float: left;
}
#motto {
 background: sienna;
  width: 300px;
  height: 20px;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}
#nav {
  background: seagreen;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  float: right;
}
```

**This is 1st fix with rearranging of divs in .html:** http://jsfiddle.net/KJG9q/

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="nav">Navigation</div>
  <div id="logo">Logo</div>
  <div id="motto">Motto</div>
</div>
```

**This is 2nd fix with another container div:** http://jsfiddle.net/x98Mf/

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="logo-motto-container">
    <div id="logo">Logo</div>
    <div id="motto">Motto</div>
  </div>
  <div id="nav">Navigation</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#logo-motto-container {
  float: left;
```

I don't want to rearrange elements in .html because I want them arranged properly for styling for mobile, I could go with another wrapper div but I want to know why the first method didn't work and if is there a fix for it without messing in .html and keeping template flexible (without position: relative)?

Comment: Best bet is a container for the sidebar content (logo and motto) in my opinion. Why don't you want to use this?

Comment: I'll use it if necessary but I wanted to understand better why it behaves like this

Comment: You are floating `div` right after the second floated left `div` thats because right floated `div` is head to head with the second left floated `div`. If you place the right floated `div` in the second place it will head to head with first `div`. Solution will be the two fixes you provide is enough!

Comment: Any updates on this question? .. Like the OP i would like to  _know what is causing this behavior_?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `float: right;` from `#nav`.

```
#nav {
    background: seagreen;
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Did you even test this? It doesn't what the author wants.

Comment: Oh! It works! You still need to add display: inline-block to div for it to work but it works. Thanks! http://jsfiddle.net/z2zqM/

Comment: This don't work after all :/ It sticks to other divs http://jsfiddle.net/6Rffa/ and I want it to stick to right border

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your fiddles so as to give you what you want to do.

The following link is the modified version of your first fix fiddle. I have just played with the css properties and not moved any of your html div's as you wanted.

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/TZ82X/3/)

```
#nav {
    background: seagreen;
    width: 100%x;
    height: 40px;    
}
```

Comment: The problem is this stick to divs on left http://jsfiddle.net/6Rffa/ and I want it to stick to right border when I resize it to smaller size

Comment: Now I exactly know what you are trying to do.

You have mentioned in your post that you want your div's to look good for mobile as well, I would suggest you to use height and width values in % in instead of px as using definite px (pixel) values will distort your page in mobile.

You can achieve the navigation div floating to right by only grouping the other two in one div as you mentioned in your 2nd Fix fiddle.

I have updated your 2nd fiddle check it out 

http://jsfiddle.net/x98Mf/2/

I haven't changed the px values of height and width to %.

Answer (score 0):

```
#nav {
    background: seagreen;
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain this please?